# Press left button mouse by using keyboard C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I want to make a program which pressing left button by using keyboard. if i press space button on keyboard it means left button mouse.
I didn't know how to give command pressing left button from mouse in wpf c# . Did anyone know ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use both the Key Press And On Mouse Click Events..Create a function which has your bussiness logic ..On Key Press And On Mouse Click Events Call That Function..Here is a sample overview..

```
public void  BusssinssLogic()
{
....
....
}

protected void onKeyPress(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 if(e.KeyCode==(Put Space Key Code Here))
  BussinessLogic();
}
```

You can code the same for Mouse Click also.

Comment: and what code so  i can order to do left mouse click in bussinesslogic() ?

Comment: In the mouseclick event you call that bussiness logic function again.It id something like this. Protected void OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e){BussinessLogic();}

Comment: i mean if i minimize the program while program running. when i pressing space twice it will running application that cursor on it.